# Indexing HTTP version of specific pages on Google via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, google-search-console, google-crawlers

Google is currently indexing the HTTPS version of my site, but i want to exclude some pages to be HTTP-indexed. How can i do this?

Best regards.

Comment: Do you have automatic redirects from HTTP to HTTPS implemented? If not, then just specify the HTTP version of the URL as `canonical` via meta tag? (But what’s the point of this anyway? Google even “punishes” sites these days for not using HTTPS, when it comes to relevance/ranking within the overall results, so … why?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.